# Aligning primary and secondary axis in charts in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a chart where I am plotting numbers and percentages (in the y-axis) and the corresponding month values in the x-axis. The number values vary from 0 to 30000 based on the months. The interval I have set is 2000 for the number and 10 for the percentage.

The number is plotted on primary axis and the percentage on the secondary axis.

The problem I am having is aligning the axis. I am not able to post the screenshot as apparently I don't have reputation enough to post images.

but this screenshot is similar to the problem I am facing.

[screenshot http://www.allaboutmssql.com/2013/08/ssrs-chart-with-two-vertical-y-axes.html](http://www.allaboutmssql.com/2013/08/ssrs-chart-with-two-vertical-y-axes.html)

Comment: Have you tried setting the axis properties so the maximum value is known for both y-axes? You can then set the interval to be a known value (perhaps a fifth of the maximum) for both axes, so stopping ssrs from guessing which lines to draw

Comment: for the percent value (secondary axis) i have set the max value which is 100. unfortunately on the primary axis i am plotting 4 different numbers - the max value is kind of unknown as it depends on the month.

Comment: Irrespective, could you set the interval to be MaxValue / 5 to keep the lines in sync?.

Comment: Alternatively is it worth turning the lines that run across the chart off for the primary X axis, leaving only the secondary (percentage) lines?

Comment: i tried the first option i am getting decimal values in the primary axis as i am plotting 2 different values in a stacked graph (i took the max of sum of the 2 values). it does not look good. if i remove the lines for the primary axis it does not look good either. i guess i will leave it to the user to see what he wants and make the changes accordingly. Thanks Jonnus.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I ran into this today and thought I'd share what I did. As Jonnus suggested in the comments, I set both axes to have the same number of intervals (in my case, 5). I also rounded the number axis upwards, so the 5 dynamic intervals would always be a round number (e.g., 28,000) and not an oddly precise number (e.g., 28,543). I did this by setting the min, max, and interval properties for each axis in turn.

For the percentage axis, I set the minimum to be 0%, the maximum to be 100%, and the interval to be 20%. This guarantees 5 intervals above 0 (20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%). In my scenario, it was a 100% stacked column chart, so they'd never be more than 100% and I could hard-code these numbers.

The number side was more challenging for me because I wanted the axis to scale dynamically based on the data. If that isn't a requirement for you, you can hard-code the min to 0, the max to your chosen number, and the interval to be the max / 5 (e.g., 0 min, 250,000 max with 25,000 intervals).

To make the number axis dynamic, it's the same principal, but I used an expression instead of hardcoding the numbers. I set the max to be whatever value comes in, rounded upwards to the next 10,000.

Max expression:

```
=Ceiling((Max(Fields!YourFieldName.Value, "YourDatasetName")) / 10000) * 10000
```

You can change the 10,000 to any interval that makes sense for your data (10, 100, 1000, 1m, etc.)

The interval formula is the same as the max expression, divided by 5:

```
=(Ceiling((Max(Fields!YourFieldName.Value, "YourDatasetName")) / 10000) * 10000) / 5
```

With these expressions, if the max value is 92,000, I round the max axis to 100,000, then divide that by 5 to give me 5 intervals of 20,000 each. If the max value is 141,000, I round the max to 150,000, divide by 5 to give me 5 intervals of 30,000. This is all dynamic.

Since both axes have 5 intervals, the gridlines always align. Both axes can be hard-coded, both can be dynamic, or you can have a mix - as long as the number of intervals is the same.

Speaking more generally, it's always a good idea to be sure a secondary axis is appropriate (vs. a separate chart). It's easy for people to read into the placement of a line on a column chart (say), even though the placement is controlled by the scale of the axes and tells you nothing about the data itself.